# How to escape "\" in exec.Command in Golang?

Tags: go

I want to execute

```
cat database_dump_1.sql | docker exec -i my_postgres psql -U postgres
```

using exec.Command method of Golang.

My code goes like this :

```
options := []string{"out.sql", "|", "docker", "exec", "-i", "my_postgres", "psql", "-U", "postgres"}
    cmd, err := exec.Command("cat", options...).Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(cmd))
```

but this fails. I guess I am not able to escape "|". I have tried "\|", but this also fails.
What am I doing wrong??

Comment: `|` doesn't need escaping. What is the error, what does `this fails` mean?

Comment: The error goes like this :  ```panic: exit status 1

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /Users/shubhamsaurav/Downloads/postgresDump/testsql.go:13 +0x143
exit status 2 . ```

Comment: BTW what you posted is *not* one command followed by arguments. It's an entire script. The results of the first command, `cat` with arguments `database_dump_1.sql` are piped to the second one, `docker` ...`. Have you tried running the entire string as-is?

Comment: You mean like this ?? ```options := []string{"out.sql | docker exec -i my_postgres psql -U postgres"}
 cmd, err := exec.Command("cat", options...).Output() ```

Comment: Or like this ```cmd, err := exec.Command("cat out.sql | docker exec -i my_postgres psql -U postgres").Output() ``` . ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#pkg-overview) say, pipelines are a shell feature which is not supported by this package:

> Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell and does not expand any glob patterns or handle other expansions, pipelines, or redirections typically done by shells.

As a quick workaround, you can try calling shell with the entire command as an argument, for example:

```
cmd := "cat out.sql | docker exec -i my_postgres psql -U postgres"
exec.Command("sh", "-c", cmd)
```

Notice that `cmd` must be a string, not a slice.